# Get the timestamp of loaded page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way in javascript or in chrome extension API to instantly (without saving the timestamp during the loading time) get the timestamp of when the DOM of the page was loaded in Chrome?

Comment: By timestamp you mean how long it took to load the page or when the page was last updated?

Comment: When the page was last updated/loaded

Comment: What kind of timestamp - exactly - are you looking for? Do you want a timestamp of when a specific article - say on Engadget - was last modified? If so, this is impossible. You're fully at the mercy of the data that's provided by the server about this. `document.lastModified` is based on the HTTP `Last-Modified` response header, for example.

Comment: Now you have attached a bounty, I recommend rewriting the question (and details) so it's more clear...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`performance.timing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.timing) object (implemented by all modern browsers, except Safari) to get [all kinds of different timestamps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming).

You need to see for yourself what timestamp would be most appropriate for you. "when the page was loaded" is quite a vague description. Otherwise, be more specific.

If you don't to go through the trouble of having a Chrome content script communicate with a Chrome background page, you can also use the [Chrome webNavigation API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation). However this only exposes events, so you'd be responsible for saving the time when this event is fired (for each page).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. I use performance.timing.domLoading as a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Click on Javascript Console from Tools menu.

Then enter the following:

```
 javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

Comment: It is not stable, for example for engadget.com I'm getting just the current timestamp every time I type document.lastModified in developer tools

Comment: Just in case any non technical people would like it clarified, press Ctrl+Shift+i, select the small Console tab if it's not already selected, then type `javascript:alert(new Date(performance.timing.domLoading))` to get it human readable.

Comment: @AnorZaken yes, your suggestion is different but better than the one given, and the answer should really be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Current document timestamp:

```
var currentDocumentTimestamp = new Date(document.lastModified).getTime();
```

Comment: This is not working for many websites, try on engadget.com for example, it always returns current timestamp. Use performance.timing.domLoading instead.