# HTML5 <video> Tag Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-video

I have a `<video>` element at the top of my page playing an animation in the background (very similar to the one found on the [Google Hangouts](http://www.google.com/hangouts/) page). On most computers, the video plays smoothly and it seems fine, but on older hardware there is a lot of lag and the browser slows down quite a lot.

Is there anyway to detect the performance of the video playback? I'd like to either replace the video with a static image or pause the video if performance is an issue.

Comment: You can use webkit profiler (profile, audit tab) that comes with web browsers like Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I'd like to detect it with JavaScript client-side so I can stop the video or replace it with an image while it is playing on a user's computer that can't handle it. Sorry for not making that clear!

Answer (score 0):

Use the video metrics if available in your browser.  Here's an example using webkit prefixed DroppedFrameCount.

http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium.git;a=blob;f=chrome/test/data/media/html/media_stat_perf.html

See also: http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_Metrics for the Moz prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Get the timestamp of loaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098117/get-the-timestamp-of-loaded-page) to determine how fast the user loads the page, then if their bandwidth is below a specified threshold, supply an image rather than the variable.